# Protrusion not working for cyrillic dash

Tags: fonts, luatex, microtype, cyrillic, protrusion

In the following LuaLaTeX MWE I am using protrusion, but it doesn't work for the cyrillic dash `"---` (it is a `babel` shortand) while working for the normal one.

```
\documentclass[10pt,draft]{scrbook}

\usepackage[showframe,textwidth=5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{polyglossia}


\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\setmainlanguage[babelshorthands=true]{russian}

\usepackage[protrusion=true,expansion=true,final]{microtype}

\setmainfont{STIX Two Text}

\SetProtrusion[%
name        =   *]{%
    encoding    =   {*},
    family      =   {*}
}{%
    \textemdash         =   {0,250},% ~---
}

\begin{document}

    \noindent%
    ББББББББ ББББББ БББ ББББ "--- ГГГГ

    \noindent%
    ББББББББ ББББББ БББ ББББ~--- ГГГГ

\end{document}
```

The output is the following:

[image]

If I insert the line `\cyrdash={0,250}` in the protusion list, I get the warning

```
Package microtype Warning: Unknown slot number of character
(microtype)                `\cyrdash '
(microtype)                in font encoding `TU' in protrusion list
(microtype)                `*'.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The construction `"---` ultimately becomes `\cyrdash`, which is defined to be

```
\hbox to 0.8em{--\hss--}
```

which means two en-dashes superimposed to occupy a space of 0.8em.

If you set protrusion for the en-dash, you get also protrusion for `\cyrdash`.

Here the value is exaggerated in order to show that protrusion is done.

```
\documentclass[10pt,draft]{scrbook}

\usepackage[showframe,textwidth=5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setmainlanguage[babelshorthands=true]{russian}

\usepackage[protrusion=true,expansion=true,final]{microtype}

\setmainfont{STIX Two Text}

\SetProtrusion[name = *]{
  encoding = {*},
  family   = {*}
}{
  \textemdash = {0,250},
  \textendash = {0,1000}, % 1000 is obviously too much!
}

\begin{document}

\noindent%
ББББББББ ББББББ БББ ББББ "--- ГГГГ

\noindent
ББББББББ ББББББ БББ ББББ~--- ГГГГ

\end{document}
```

[image]